# Prescribed way to set cookies (from plugin or Twig)

Tags: plugin-development, cookies

From either a plugin or a Twig template, is there a prescribed way to set (and get) cookies?

I've seen https://github.com/lewisjenkins/craft-lj-cookies/, which just uses PHP's `setcookie`.

Also noticed `getCookie` in `craft.request`. https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.request#getCookie

I've noticed the cookies set with `setcookie` aren't readable by `getCookie`. How should one set a cookie so that it is readable by `getCookie`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cookies cannot be set via templates. However, in a plugin you have access to Craft's services. The `UserSessionService` has the `saveCookie` function.

```
craft()->userSession->saveCookie($cookieName, $data, $duration);
```

Comment: Here is a conveniently written plugin that does just that: http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/lj-cookies

Comment: Perfect, `craft()->userSession->saveCookie` and `craft()->userSession->getCookieValue` is what I was looking for.

Comment: @BradBell that plugin just uses setcookie, I was looking to make it work with the `craft()->security` checks.

Answer (score 6):

I wrote a plugin similar to lj_cookies that accomplishes this for both regular and craft secure cookies:

- Craft 2.x: [Cookies](https://github.com/nystudio107/cookies)
- Craft 3.x: [Cookies](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-cookies)

...enjoy.

Comment: Is it possible to use this on a click event? I want to set some cookies on CTA's and trying to think of a way to handle that.

Comment: I'd use JavaScript for that

Answer (score 4):

In the new Craft 3, you can use the following in your plugin:

```
// Create cookie object.
$cookie = Craft::createObject([
    'class' => 'yii\web\Cookie',
    'name' => 'CookiesAccepted', 
    'httpOnly' => true,
    'value' => 'true',
    'expire' => time() + (86400 * 365),
]);

// Set cookie.
Craft::$app->getResponse()->getCookies()->add($cookie);
```

To get the cookie's value, use:

```
Craft::$app->request->cookies->get('CookiesAccepted');
```

Comment: can we add the cookie in plaintext? Currently, it encodes the value.

Comment: @inrsaurabh you'd have to create cookies in the vanilla PHP way https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_network_setcookie.asp

Answer (score 1):

To access a cookie you can use the plugin variable class

```php
<?php

namespace Craft;

/**
 * Class PluginVariable
 * @package Craft
 */
class PluginVariable
{
    /**
     * Get the cookie value
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPluginCookie($name)
    {
        return $_COOKIE[$name] ?? '';
    }
}
```

And inside your twig file you call

`{% set pluginCookie = craft.plugin.getPluginCookie('some_cookie_name') %}`