# Best way to use saveCookie and craft.request.getCookie('location')

Tags: cookies

Following up on this question: [Prescribed way to set cookies (from plugin or Twig)](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/648/prescribed-way-to-set-cookies-from-plugin-or-twig) the following works great.

```
craft()->userSession->saveCookie($cookieName, $data, $duration);
```

I can see **Location** being set as my cookie in the Application Log but when I try to use `{{ craft.request.getCookie('location') }}` It returns blank.

What am I missing here?

**Edit** - Upon closer inspection it doesn't look like saveCookie is working correctly either. I see location from when I was using setFlash but I need the data to persist even if the page is reloaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably be using something like this:

```
    $cookie = new HttpCookie($name, $value);
    $cookie->expire = time() + 3600;

    craft()->request->getCookies()->add($cookie->name, $cookie);
```

Setting whatever properties you want on [HttpCookie](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/etc/web/HttpCookie).

Using [UserSessionService](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/UserSessionService)->[saveCookie](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/UserSessionService#saveCookie-detail) is meant mainly for Craft's session identity cookie, so it has some security checks it goes through saving the cookie that `craft.request.getCookie('location')` is probably failing.

Comment: Dear Brad - you're my hero.

Comment: Does this work in Craft 3?  I'm setting a cookie using js-cookie and it's not returning anything in my twig templates.

Comment: I went for a plugin instead and it's working nicely in Craft 3: https://github.com/nystudio107/cookies

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a plugin similar to lj_cookies that accomplishes this for both regular and craft secure cookies: [Cookies](https://github.com/nystudio107/cookies)

https://github.com/nystudio107/cookies

...enjoy.