# Craft 3: Recognize cookies created in Craft 2

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, cookies

In Craft 2, we could set a cookie like this...

```php
craft()->userSession->saveCookie()
```

... and that would make it a *state* cookie. [This thread](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/13881/45) describes it pretty well. Essentially, you would end up with a cookie whose name began with a hashed string.

> b72b7553c36d6600e9aeb6c40513deb8**MyCookie**

However, it seems like that behavior has been largely removed in Craft 3. When I try to save a cookie now, I do it more like this...

```php
$cookie = new Cookie();
$cookie->name = $cookieName;
$cookie->value = $cookieValue;
$cookie->expire = time() + $lifespan;
Craft::$app->getResponse()->getCookies()->add($cookie);
```

... which *doesn't* create a state cookie. The cookie name is very simple.

> **MyCookie**

Generally speaking, that doesn't bother me. But I worry about compatibility issues with the Craft 2 version of my plugin. It's somewhat important that cookies from the old system are recognized when Craft is upgraded.

**What is the solution for this?** How do I ensure that my old cookies are recognized properly, and/or continue saving this data using the original hashed format?

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of trial & error, it turns out this is **not possible**. (At least, not by me.)

I was able to retrieve the raw Craft 2 cookie data using the following code...

```php
// Generate hash of Craft 2 cookie
private function _getCraft2CookieHash()
{
    $newBasePath = Craft::$app->getBasePath();
    $oldBasePath = str_replace('vendor/craftcms/cms/src', 'app', $newBasePath);
    $appId = sprintf('%x',crc32($oldBasePath.'Craft'));
    return md5('Yii.Craft\UserSessionService.'.$appId);
}

// Get existing Craft 2 cookie data
public function getExistingCookieData()
{
    // Get name of Craft 2 cookie
    $craft2CookieHash = $this->_getCraft2CookieHash();
    $craft2CookieName = $craft2CookieHash.'MyCookie';

    // If Craft 2 cookie exists
    if (isset($_COOKIE[$craft2CookieName])) {

        // Get value of Craft 2 cookie
        $cookieValue = $_COOKIE[$craft2CookieName];

        /**
         * THIS IS WHERE IT ALL FELL APART
         * The cookie data is too highly encoded.
         */

    }
}
```

I was able to correctly determine the hash which makes up part of the Craft 2 cookie's name. Keep in mind, **this only works if the site's folder structure did not change.** The docs give you [two different ways](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/upgrade.html) to upgrade the site from Craft 2, and this hash-detection logic will only work if you choose to "keep your current directory structure".

However, things really fell apart when trying to get the actual *data* from the cookie. The data is encoded in some very complex ways. In Craft 2, it uses a complicated function called `computeHMAC` which goes way beyond my understanding of security. There is no equivalent function in Craft 3 (and if there was, it would probably operate quite differently).

Sadly, I have to throw in the towel and admit defeat here. Backwards engineering the `computeHMAC` function is more than my puny brain can handle. :(